# Loops for extracting vector percentiles

Tags: r, dplyr

I am extracting the percentile values for each of my variables using the `findInterval` function. I am then exporting the IDs and percentiles for each variable. I can do this individually, but when using `lapply` to automate this process I get an error.

Below is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVar <- c(1,2,4,6,1,2,4,6,1,2,4,8,1,2,7,6) 
   ID VarA VarB VarC VarD ControlVar perc_VarA
1   1    1   10   10   10          1         1
2   2    1    0   12   12          2         1
3   3    1    0   14   14          4         1
4   4    1    0   16   16          6         1
5   5    1   12   10   10          1         1
6   6    1   12   12   12          2         1
7   7    1   12   14   14          4         1
8   8    1   12   16   16          6         1
9   9    1    0   10   10          1         1
10 10    1   14   12   12          2         1
11 11    1   NA   14   14          4         1
12 12   14   14   16   16          8        92
13 13   NA   16   10   10          1        NA
14 14   NA   16   12   12          2        NA
15 15   NA   16   14   14          7        NA
16 16   16   16   16   16          6       100
```

Below is the code I am using to extract the desired datasets which is giving me an error. When I omit the `findInterval` command the code runs fine (so I do not believe the error is associated with the 'rename' function in `lapply`)

```
columns <- df %>% colnames(.)

lapply(columns, function(x)
df %>% 
  mutate(perc = findInterval(all_of(x), quantile(all_of(x), probs=1:100/100, na.rm = TRUE), left.open=T) + 1) %>% 
  select(ID, perc) %>% 
  rename(!!paste0("perc_", all_of(x)) := perc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Instead of `lapply`, you can use `across` to apply a function to several columns in your data.frame:

```r
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVar <- c(1,2,4,6,1,2,4,6,1,2,4,8,1,2,7,6)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~findInterval(.x,
                                   quantile(.x, probs=1:100/100, na.rm = TRUE),
                                   left.open=T) + 1, .names = "perc_{.col}")) %>% 
  select(ID, starts_with("perc"))
#>    ID perc_VarA perc_VarB perc_VarC perc_VarD perc_ControlVar
#> 1   1         1        29         1         1               1
#> 2   2         1         1        27        27              27
#> 3   3         1         1        54        54              54
#> 4   4         1         1        80        80              74
#> 5   5         1        36         1         1               1
#> 6   6         1        36        27        27              27
#> 7   7         1        36        54        54              54
#> 8   8         1        36        80        80              74
#> 9   9         1         1         1         1               1
#> 10 10         1        65        27        27              27
#> 11 11         1        NA        54        54              54
#> 12 12        92        65        80        80             100
#> 13 13        NA        79         1         1               1
#> 14 14        NA        79        27        27              27
#> 15 15        NA        79        54        54              94
#> 16 16       100        79        80        80              74
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

---

### Edit

Here is a way to use `lapply`:

```r
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVar <- c(1,2,4,6,1,2,4,6,1,2,4,8,1,2,7,6)

library(dplyr)

names_to_track <- colnames(df)[-1] # exclude the ID column

# with lapply
res <- lapply(names_to_track, function(var_name) {
  new_name <- paste0("perc_", var_name)
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!new_name := findInterval(.data[[var_name]],
                                                     quantile(.data[[var_name]], probs=1:100/100, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                     left.open=T) + 1) %>% 
    select(ID, .data[[new_name]])
})

str(res)
#> List of 5
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ID       : int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ perc_VarA: num [1:16] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ID       : int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ perc_VarB: num [1:16] 29 1 1 1 36 36 36 36 1 65 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ID       : int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ perc_VarC: num [1:16] 1 27 54 80 1 27 54 80 1 27 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ID       : int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ perc_VarD: num [1:16] 1 27 54 80 1 27 54 80 1 27 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ ID             : int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..$ perc_ControlVar: num [1:16] 1 27 54 74 1 27 54 74 1 27 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Straja, Thanks for your response. Yes, you are right, this can be done using `across` to apply the function to multiple columns (which has the the benefit of renaming the new columns). I was hoping to later be able to use `lapply` so that I could create separate files for each ID/variable produced. But I can use apply `lapply` to achieve this once I have the new dataset achieved with the solution you highlighted above. Thanks Straja

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks, Straja!